# Displaying the imanges without text in a column

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I'm using `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider`. I have a table with a column that has only icons without text. So the `getText` method is:

```
@Override
public String getText(final Object element) {
    return "";
}
```

When user press the column it sorts it by using the following `compare` method:

```
@Override
public int compare(final Viewer viewer, final Object e1, final Object e2) {
    if (null != columnLabelProvider) {
        String s1 = columnLabelProvider.getText(e1);
        String s2 = columnLabelProvider.getText(e2);

        s1 = null == s1 ? "" : s1;
        s2 = null == s2 ? "" : s2;

        return direction * s1.compareTo(s2);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The way I create it:

```
for (final String name: names) {
    final TreeViewerColumn column = createColumn(name, true);
    final StepStatusColumnLabelProvider provider = new StepStatusColumnLabelProvider(name);
    column.setLabelProvider(provider);
    column.getColumn().addSelectionListener(new ColumnSelectionListener(column.getColumn(), provider));
}
```

I would like to sort the columns of icons, so I changed the `getText` method to be:

```
@Override
public String getText(final Object element) {
    if (element instanceof StatusNode) {
        final StatusNode node = (StatusNode) element;
        return node.getStepStatusType(stepName).name();
    }
    return "";
}
```

It works but now the strings are shown in the column. How can I sort the column without actually displaying the text?

Comment: Change what the `compare` method actually compares rather than the results of `getText()`.

Comment: @nitind Do you mean to handle case `StepStatusColumnLabelProvider` in the `compare` method? I'm not sure that I can check if `columnLabelProvider` is instance of `StepStatusColumnLabelProvider` because the hierarchy is the other way around. I prefer not to change the call to `getText()` because I will have to change all of the other providers.

Comment: You're the one setting *which* label provider to use on the table viewer, yes? I meant create a subclass of the label provider and have your `compare` method act the way you want it to. `getText()` was already doing what it was supposed to do--conforming to its interface--when you returned an empty string.

Comment: Is it possible without creating a new class? Both classes are basically the same, the only difference will be the method call from `compare` (one will call `getText` and the other one `getImageText`). I thought of checking in the `compare` method the class of the instance and if it is `StepStatusColumnLabelProvider` than I should call `getImageText` by using casting `((StepStatusColumnLabelProvider) columnLabelProvider).getImageText(e1)`. But I can't import `StepStatusColumnLabelProvider` into `ColumnComparator` because they are in different packages.

Comment: I don't know the fully qualified names of all of those, but this sounds like a reason to make a subclass or a delegate.